# javascript loop in objects

Tags: javascript

I have data like this

```
 data = {
      products: { medicare: {"11":"plan1", "12":"plan2", "13":"plan3", "14":"plan14"},
       medigap: {"112":"plan12", "122":"plan22", "132":"plan32", "142":"plan142"}
      }}

plan1 =medicare;
plan2 = medigap
```

If user selected plan1 then I need results like this

```
results = [plan1, plan2, plan3, plan14];
```

if user selected plan2 then the results should be

```
results = [plan12, plan22, plan32, plan142];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
function getPlan(plan) {
  return Object.values(data.products[plan])
}
```

- `plan1` would be `medicare`
- `plan2` would be `medigap`

Usage:

- `getPlan(plan1)` returns `['plan1', 'plan2', 'plan3', 'plan14']`
- `getPlan(plan2)` returns `['plan12', 'plan22', 'plan32', 'plan142']`

Answer (score 2):

After finding product with selected `plan`, you can use `Object.values` to find the plans.

```js
var data = {
      products: { 
        medicare: {"11":"plan1", "12":"plan2", "13":"plan3", "14":"plan14"},
       medigap: {"112":"plan12", "122":"plan22", "132":"plan32", "142":"plan142"}
      }
 }
 var userSelected = 'medicare';
 
 var product = data.products[userSelected];
 var plans = Object.values(product);
 console.log(plans);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
data_sample = {
      products: { medicare: {"11":"plan1", "12":"plan2", "13":"plan3", "14":"plan14"},
       medigap: {"112":"plan12", "122":"plan22", "132":"plan32", "142":"plan142"}
      }}

plan1 ="medicare";
plan2 = "medigap";


var get_data = data_sample['products'][plan2];
var list = []

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(get_data)) {
  console.log(value);
  list.push(value);
}
console.log(list);
```

Try this logic. You need to put some effort to refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your planname dynamically in the loop and you will get the desired result.

```
plan1 = 'medicare';
plan2 = 'medigap';
resultArr = [];
Object.entries(data.products[plan1]).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  resultArr.push(value);
});

console.log(resultArr);
```